# How to make sharp and rounded corners

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges

I'm trying all kinds of options to make sharp edges and rounded corners for an excavator arm. Apart from just using bevel, I also have tried to use "make sharp" and "edge crease", but it doesn't look nice. Any suggestion have I can improve my model with more edges and where to put them or any other approach to make rounded corners with sharp edges?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're modeling using subdivision, at its simplest, this sort of topology will give you a rounded corner: supporting loops close to the sharp edges, and looser on the round corner. You have a degree of control over the tightness of the corner by sliding the edges on either side of it.

[[image]

[image]

[image]

However, if, for example, you you wanted a perfect circular arc in the corner, breaking instantly to perfectly orthogonal edges, you might choose a bevel, as suggested by atek.

Answer (score 0):

With the knife tool cut this way

[image]

To make an edge. With the edge selected Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bevel and with the mouse wheel make the segments and how much round shape you need